# How to parse a JSONObject from Firebase realtime database into an ArrayList in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to parse JSONObject from Firebase realtime database into an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> picture_profile = new ArrayList<String>();
```

-----------------------------------json object----------------------------

```
{ 
   "testuser1": { 
      "password": "123456", 
      "picture_profile": "default" 
   }, 
   "testuser2": { 
      "password": "123456", 
      "picture_profile": "default" 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should [edit] your question and post some [mcve]. Otherwise your question will be closed as off-topic/too broad. And if possible please take the [tour] and learn how StackOverflow community works.

Answer (score 1):

this code in kotlin, you can use this scenerio in java also but you have to change syntax.

First ,change json Structure like that

```
{ 
   "userList":[ { 
      "username":"testuser1",
      "password": "123456", 
      "picture_profile": "default" 
   }, 
     { 
      "username":"testuser2",
      "password": "123456", 
      "picture_profile": "default" 
   } 
]
}
```

Second, add listener to get value of userList

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("userList")
 database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                if(dataSnapshot?.hasChild("userList")!!){
                    val memberList = dataSnapshot.child("userList")?.value as ArrayList<*>
                    val tempFriendList = getFriendList(memberList)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(dataSnapshot: DatabaseError?) {
            }

        })
```

and Third, add this method to get value in ArrayList

```
fun getUserList(UserDataList: ArrayList<*>): ArrayList<MemberUserInfoModel> {
            val size = UserDataList.size
            var index = 0
            val userList = ArrayList<MemberUserInfoModel>()

            while (index < size) {
                val hashMap: HashMap<*, *> = UserDataList[index] as HashMap<*, *>
                val userName = hashMap["username"].toString()
                val password = hashMap["password"].toString()
                val pictureProfile = hashMap["picture_profile"].toString()
                userList.add(MemberUserInfoModel(userName,password,pictureProfile))
                index++
            }
            return userList
        }
```

model for ArrayList is shown below

```
class MemberUserInfoModel : Serializable {
    lateinit var username: String
    lateinit var password: String
    lateinit var pictureProfile: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having three arraylist create a model class and use arraylist of that class. Inside the model class give filds username, password and profile_pic.

```
public class UserDetails {

    public String name;
    public String password;
    public String proPic;

    public UserDetails(String name, String image, String proPic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.proPic = proPic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
     public String getproPic() {
        return proPic;
    }
}
```

Then inside onDataChange parse the data

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    UserDetails userDetails = postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
    userDetailsArray.add(0, userDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just copy your json response to this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org), and set the property like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBneU.png)

you can pass your json response to in java object.

Answer (score 0):

-First of all create getter setter class of your JsonObject

-after that use datasnapshot object and you are able to access that data
-Create one arraylist of UserdetailsArray:

```
ArrayList<UserDetails> userdetails=new ArrayList();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("YourField").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Get Data", postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class).toString());
            userDetailsArray.add(postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```